# How can I use Physics2D.OverlapPoint to reference the overlapping object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I currently have a set of "holder" objects and a set of "card" objects. The card objects can be dragged around and are snapped into place on top of the holder object if the mouse is released while on top of a holder object. I also have an array where each position on the array will correspond to a specific holder to know which card is in which holder. I am using Physics2D.OverlapPoint for the position snapping and need to be able to send that info to the array. I am doing all of the code in C#.

```
Collider2D hit0 = Physics2D.OverlapPoint(positionPlH0, Cards);
        if (hit0 != null)   //hit returns the 2D box collider of the card in that holder
        {
            Debug.Log(hit0);
            InPlayCards[0] = hit0;
        }
```

hit0 is returning the following: PCard5 (UnityEngine.BoxCollider2D)

I need to be able to reference the actual card object rather than just it's collider so that I can send that info to the array. If there is a better way to do this process please let me know.

Comment: Have you not seen that like all monobehaviours there is a variable of ggameObject in the collider class that references the gameobject the collider is on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of the `GetComponent` functions to get a specific component on the object.

`GetComponent` - Use this if the component is on the same object as the collider.

`GetComponentInChildren` - Use this if the component is on this object or one of the children.

`GetComponentInParent` - Use this if the component is on this object or one of the parent objects.

```
if (hit0 != null)
{
    var card = hit0.GetComponent<Card>();
    if (card)
    {
        // Do stuff with card.
    }
}
```

To get the `GameObject`, simply use `hit0.gameObject`.

[Collider2d Reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.html)

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I'm not looking to get a specific component of the object. The hit0 is returning the collider component of the gameObject, and I need to reference the gameObject itself, not a component of it. I cannot directly reference the gameObject at the start because there can be multiple of the same card, and the cards in play are randomized.

Comment: updated my answer with the gameobject reference

Comment: So my comment was exactly what you needed.

Comment: Thank you! It was probably a stupid question, but I just couldn't seem to figure it out!

Comment: Thats where unitys scripting reference comes in handy.  I included the Collider2d reference in my answer.  You can see under inherited properties, `gameObject` is inherited from Component.  This means that anything that can be attached to a `GameObject` will have this property available.

Comment: As a shorthand you can even directly use `if(hit0.TryGetComponent<Card>(out var card){ ... }`